# DNS resolution fails in web browser but nslookup succeeds

Tags: windows-7, dns, active-directory, windows-server-2012

We are a small, 300-seat organization with a mixed BYOD and Active Directory environment (Windows Server 2012 Standard, Windows 7 Enterprise) and we are having a very strange problem involving very specific-scope failures to resolve our organization's domain name on our domain-joined, company-controlled machines.  For the purpose of this discussion, I'll use **company.com** instead of our domain name.

**Background:**

- Active Directory Domain Controller is located at 172.16.1.3
- The AD/DC machine is also running DHCP, DNS, and HTTP (IIS)
- Our organizations websites at **company.com** and **subdomain.company.com** are hosted by IIS on the AD/DC machine
- We have a split-DNS scenario in which the AD/DC server is used for internal DNS resolution but a different, off-site server provides DNS resolution for public queries
- The IP address corresponding to **company.com** and **subdomain.company.com** is the public IP address used by a firewall at the edge of our network (both on the AD/DC DNS server and the off-site DNS server)
- The firewall is correctly configured for NAT to pass HTTP and HTTPS requests it receives on its public IP address to the internal IP of the AD/DC server and reflects

**Scenario 1:**

- A user on a domain-joined Windows 7 Enterprise machine is connected directly to our local network with local address 172.16.6.100 /16, issued by the DHCP server.
- The DNS server entry is provided by DHCP (172.16.1.3)
- This user is able to access the websites hosted at company.com and subdomain.company.com
- **Edit:** nslookup has been run in this scenario and correctly returns the proper DNS record from the internal DNS server (172.16.1.3)

**Scenario 2:**

- The same user on the same domain-joined Windows 7 Enterprise machine goes home and connects to the Internet using their residential ISP
- The IP and DNS server entries for the client machine are provided by DHCP
- This user can access any internet resources, such as google.com
- This user cannot access the website at **company.com** or **subdomain.company.com** (a "host not resolved" error is returned)
- When this user runs nslookup on **company.com** they **DO** receive the correct public IP address provided by DNS
- HTTP/HTTPS requests to the IP address succeed and a webpage is returned properly by the server
- This issue prevails across all web browsers
- Using **tracert company.com** returns "unable to resolve target system name"
- Using **ping company.com** returns "could not find host company.com"
- When running Wireshark on the client before/during a failed request, no packets are sent by the client machine (either for DNS resolution or for an initial HTTP/ping/tracert request)
- Restarting the DNS Client service does not resolve the problem
- Stopping the DNS Client service does not resolve the problem
- Using **ipconfig /flushdns** does not resolve this issue
- Using **route /f** does not resolve this issue
- Resetting the network connections using **netsh int ip reset** does not resolve this issue
- **Edit:** nslookup has been run in this scenario and correctly returns the proper DNS record from the DNS server specified by the DHCP settings of the network used by the user

**Scenario 3:**

- This same user on a personal (not domain-joined) Windows 7 Professional computer is able to access the websites at **company.com** and **subdomain.company.com** when connected to our local network
- **Edit:** nslookup has been run in this scenario and correctly returns the proper DNS record from the internal DNS server (172.16.1.3)

**Scenario 4:**

- This same user on a personal (not domain-joined) Windows 7 Professional computer is able to access the websites at **company.com** and **subdomain.company.com** when connected their home network
- **Edit:** nslookup has been run in this scenario and correctly returns the proper DNS record from the DNS server specified by the DHCP settings of the network used by the user

**Final Notes:**

This issue seems to be generalized to affect all company-owned computers.  We are using a common system image for all company-owned computers, which was just loaded in August.  I have been scouring the internet in search of possible solutions and have come up empty handed so far -- I really appreciate any suggestions or advice you may have.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an interesting scenario. Looking at your scenario 3, user with personal computer can access the services but why is the DNS entry coming from your corporate IP and not users home DNS. Is the machine on company network?

Verify this:

- When user tries to access service from home on company computer, is the IP details from home internet router or company network via VPN?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  Yes, as I describe in Scenario 3, the user-owned computer is connected to our network so they receive their IP and DNS configuration from our local DHCP server.  Scenario 4 is the answer to your question -- when the user takes their computer home, it receives IP and DNS configuration from their home network and can still access our server successfully.  Our VPN is not involved in any of these scenarios.

Comment: OK will recommend you do this:

- From non working computer, open command prompt
- Type: nslookup
- Type: set type=all
- Type: company.com

Review or post the result stripping out company info

Comment: OK, the sanitized output from a test client (Scenario 2) is at the pastebin link below (too long for an in-comment paste).  Any ideas?  **[http://pastebin.com/w0DS8LyP](http://pastebin.com/w0DS8LyP)**